# Executing sudo via plumbum in python3

Tags: python-3.x, sudo

Can someone please help me out with the below code. Trying to figure out how to execute sudo commands via plumbum

```
from plumbum import cmd

osTyp = cmd.uname('-s').strip()
print('The Os is:', osTyp)

def S1():
    if osTyp == 'Linux':
        cmd.sudo(["systemctl", "stop", "dbora.service"])
```

Comment: Are you facing any error ? Cause `cmd.sudo` is how we execute sudo cmds in plumbum and you are not calling the S1 function in your sample code

Answer (score 0):

from plumbum import cmd

osTyp = cmd.uname('-s').strip()
print('The Os is:', osTyp)

if osTyp == 'Linux':
     cmd.sudo(["systemctl", "stop", "dbora.service"])